# Custom Javascript not loading in Revolution Slider

Tags: javascript, slider

So I've tried the following Javascript in the custom Javascript box in Revolution Slider and just in a text box in the slider itself.

It renders appropriately while designing, but upon execution, nothing renders from the Javascript code. Any ideas how or where to enter this code into Revolution Slider?

```js
<script type="text/javascript">

var thehours = new Date().getHours();
 var themessage;
 var day = ('02 1111 1111');
 var after = ('0411 000 000');

 if (thehours >= 9 && thehours < 17) {
  themessage = day; 

 } else if (thehours >= 17 && thehours < 24) {
  themessage = after;

 } else if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 9) {
  themessage = after;
 }

document.getElementById('myLink').innerHTML=themessage;

var link = "tel:" + themessage.replace(/ /g, "");

document.getElementById("myLink").href=link;

</script>
```

```html
<span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:17px;padding:10px;display:block;text-indent:-0.5em;">Call to Discuss <span style="font-family:Wingdings;font-size:19px;">&#41;</span>&nbsp;<a id="myLink"></a>&nbsp;<span style="font-family:Wingdings;font-size:19px;">&#41;</span> 24 Hours</span>
```

Comment: Are you getting a JavaScript error?

Comment: I copied your code snippet to write an answer and discovered that removing the `script` tags from the code snippet caused the phone number to show up when running the snippet. Did you put your code in a blank HTML page to see if it works?

Comment: No javascript error, it just doesn't render in the live version, but renders fine in the preview version when designing it in Revolution Slider.

Comment: And yep the code is working in other applications - just not in revolution slider.

Comment: Is the `<span>` tag in the HTML source before the `<script>` tag?

Comment: Maybe the revolution sidebar is introducing an HTML syntax error?

Comment: Having the span tag before the script tag in a php file was what solved the problem for me in a separate application of this code. But I think it is something Revolution Slider specific causing it to not render as it renders fine in the preview version.

Comment: Without seeing the revolution slider, the code used to generate it, or the rendered output in the browser I don't think we can properly answer this question.

Comment: If you try somethig basic instead of the all code (eg: `document.getElementById('myLink').innerHTML='test';` ), does it render ?

Comment: Following Martial's suggestion, it renders 'test' in the design phase of revolution slider but not in the actual phase, similar as the full code.

Comment: Fixed it... One of the ID's I was using was already being used in a hidden topbar causing the 2nd <a> tag with that ID not to load...